# Is there a right or wrong practice when using IF statements : if(foo) or if(foo == true)?

Tags: validation, if-statement, logic

Throughout my (short) career so far in programming (merely a student working on internship) I have noticed that when it comes to IF statements, there is two different ways of doing it.

If we take `foo` as a boolean value:

```
if(foo)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This is my preferred way of doing things when dealing with IF statements, if I'm looking for false I use:

```
if(!foo)
{
    //do more stuff
}
```

However, when some people see this they raise an eyebrow, suggesting that I may be stuck in  a bad habit. But I wanted to know, is there any difference between this way or the "typical" way?

```
if(foo == true)
{
    //do a bit more stuff
}
```

Am I falling into a common trap for new programmers? Or is there no difference (at least a noticeable one)

Comment: "when some people see this they raise an eyebrow"... really? I would raise an eyebrow at the `== true` version.

Comment: This is what I thought! I always thought it made more sense to do it the way I usually do, in University we were shown the == true way but I also thought the first way looked neater too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never write == true or == false. It goes against the point of an if-sentence, in my opinion.

an if is basicly: If a Boolean expression is true, do something. a Boolean is a boolean expression in and of itself, so why wrap it?

So in my opinion, the ones using == true are the ones with a bad habit. Becuase they display ignorance of how the language works.

think of these "allowed" ways to write if (Foo) and if (!Foo):

```
if (Foo == true) //If Foo is the same as true
if (Foo != true //If Foo is not the same as true
if (Foo != false) //if Foo is not the same as false
if (Foo == false) //If Foo is the same as false
if (Foo) //If Foo
if (!Foo) //If not Foo
```

using == and != with booleans actually introduce new ways to make mistakes both when programming and reading code.

Boolean and !Boolean is hard to misread.

Comment: The list of "allowed" ways illustrates the issue in a great way.

Comment: This is a great answer, and now I'm sure that _I'm_ the one doing it right!

Answer (score 1):

I guess doing it your way is recommended in most of the languages

```
if(foo)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

For instance **Python [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says**

Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.

```
Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

Another example from **[Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449)**

The if-else class of statements should have the following form:

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
}
```

Just the small tip:
Speaking about condition checks, here's the good tip I've heard few weeks ago
If you compare for instance in C like

`if(variable == "value") ....`

you can get to the problems that if you write by accident `if (variable = "value") ...`
compiler will not throw an error, so some people use the convention of `if ("value" == variable) ...`, then if you write by accident `=` instead of `==`, compiler will throw an error

Comment: Do you feel make these errors often enough to justify the lessened readability of inverting the sentence? In C# you will get compiler warning, so I always write the way I read. I also do that in other languages, because I have yet to make this error more than a few times.

Comment: This answer was useful, the reference is useful too :)

Answer (score 0):

Most coding conventions tell you that boolean checks are tested as

```
if(someBoolean) {
```

or

```
if(!someBoolean) {
```

This simply improves readability. If you are unsure, check out some code conventions, here are the Java ones for you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0):

Checking `if(foo == true)` means

> check if foo is equal to true is equal to true

Which is just an overhead according to me.