# Too many methods?

Tags: java, structure

This class I just wrote does actually work the way I want it to. My question is am I breaking it down into too many methods? It almost seems excessive, but it looked horrible all cramped in main method.  But now I have 6 little methods (7 including main).  I guess I am looking for general feedback. Thanks so much!

Should I include a brief explanation of what's happening in this class so people can better understand?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DuplicateElimination 
{
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int[] numberArray = new int[5];  
private static int initialInput = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Arrays.fill(numberArray, 0); //initialize array

    for (int x = 0; x < numberArray.length; x++) // perform 5x
    {
        initialInput =getNumber(); //get number from user

        boolean inRange = checkRange(); // check if number in range
        if (inRange == true)
        {   
            boolean uniqueNumber = uniqueNumber();//check if number is unique
            if (uniqueNumber == true)
            {
                numberArray[0]=initialInput; //add number to array
                printUniqueNumbers();

            }
            else 
                notUniqueNumber();
        }
        else
        {
            notInRange();
            x--; // do not count out-of-range numbers as one of the 5 numbers
        }
    }//end for  
}//end main

public static int getNumber()
{
    System.out.printf("Please enter a unique number between 10 and 100:  ");
    int initialInput = input.nextInt();
    return initialInput;
}//end getNumber

public static boolean checkRange()
{
    boolean inRange;
    if ((initialInput >=10) && (initialInput <= 100))
        inRange = true;
    else
        inRange = false;
        return inRange;
}//end checkRange

public static boolean uniqueNumber()
{
    boolean uniqueNumber;
    Arrays.sort(numberArray);
    int location = Arrays.binarySearch(numberArray, initialInput);
    if (location <= 0)
        uniqueNumber = true;
    else
        uniqueNumber = false;
    return uniqueNumber;

}//end uniqueNumber

public static void printUniqueNumbers()
{
    System.out.println("List of unique numbers entered:  ");
    for (int n = 0; n < numberArray.length; n++)
        if (numberArray[n] != 0)
            System.out.print(numberArray[n] + " ");
    System.out.println("\n");
}//end printUniqueNumbers

public static void notUniqueNumber()
{
    System.out.print("You already input " + initialInput + ".\n\n");
    printUniqueNumbers();       
}

public static void notInRange()
{
    System.out.println("Number is out of range.  Please try again.\n");
}

}//end class
```

Comment: It's really opinion based. Some people like to use as little code as possible, so if they can get by without a method for something, they will; others will break every task into a different method. Most of the time it's better to break it up, like you did.

Comment: You really should ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - there are several points to be addressed. This site here is oriented towards fixing problems in your code. But test your program - does it really work? Then edit your question here.

Comment: [This might help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195989/is-it-ok-to-split-long-functions-and-methods-into-smaller-ones-even-though-they)

Comment: I think that looks quite okay. You could perhaps extract what's in `checkRange`/`uniqueNumber` and the array initialization code into a separate class and let this one only handle the UI part (input/output).

Comment: Also, look at the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976344/is-there-a-right-or-wrong-practice-when-using-if-statements-iffoo-or-iffoo/14976525#14976525

Comment: Related to the previous comment: Instead of `if(a < b){ x = true; } else { x = false; }` most prefer `x = a < b;`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suitted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is more a code review question, but using many methods with clear names is a very good clean code practice. (As long as the methods are private and dont use fields for data dependency of course). It helps reduce source indention, provides clear scoping and the high level functions are easy to follow. It is however important that the names are not mossleading (for example getSomething() should not have sideeffects). Your "notInRange()" method is however not very helpful named or actually better left as a print. And your data flow with statics is also a bad pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Java method is a collection of statements that are grouped together to
>   perform an operation.Here in this example in each method it is dealing with single task.So it is good so far.Here i think you are worried about  *Commenting* and *Readability*

Two types of comments are

- *implementation comments* :- meant for commenting out code or for comments     about the particular implementation
- *documentation comments*  :- meant to describe the specification of the code, from an implementation-free perspective.

> I think you can give some Documentation Comments for the class `DuplicateElimination` Something like this.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * The DuplicateElimination class provides ...
>  */
> public class DuplicateElimination { ...
> ```

---

*Formatting*

When coding Java classes and interfaces, the following formatting rules should be followed:

- No space between a method name and the parenthesis "(" starting its parameter list.
- Open brace "{" appears at the end of the same line as the declaration statement.
- Closing brace "}" starts a line by itself indented to match its corresponding opening statement, except when it is a null statement the "}" should appear immediately after the "{".
- Methods are separated by a blank line

In this case,

```
class DuplicateElimination {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);;
    private static int[] numberArray = new int[5];
    private static int initialInput = 0

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.fill(numberArray, 0); //initialize array;
        ....

    }

    int emptyMethod() {}

    ...
}
```

If you are in Eclipse

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` will do.

---

*Readability*

Here are some of the programming or coding best practices professional Java developer follow while writing code.Which makes code super readable.

1. *Avoid Pointless Names*

   Pointless names e.g. variable names as abc, temp, data etc doesn't reveal intent, they simply reduce readability.
2. *Give Meaningful Names*

   This is counterpart of first coding best practice. Instead of pointless names, provide meaningful names, which reveals intent of programmer
3. *Prefer shorter name over longer one, if it reveal intent clearly.*

   I love to use short name for my methods but only if it's complete and reveal programmer's intention clearly.shorter ones are easy to read and write, but don't forget to follow Java bean naming convention

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/10/10-java-best-practices-to-name-variables-methods-classes-packages.html#ixzz3onnVpS2s

Comment: Are there really any "pointless names" in this program? If no - why this answer?

Comment: Why dont you answer then?

Comment: See my three comments.

Comment: That is very nice point,but @Bianca is concerned about something else, i guess

Comment: She wrote, "I am looking for general feedback", and this doesn't exclude anything.

Comment: I think i did the same "looking for general feedback".Should i delete the answer?

Comment: No - it'll be closed anyway. - I just wondered why you picked this topic because the names in that program are fine (except x - if you are picky).

Comment: Note that in C, C++, Java and some other languages there are two "schools of thought" as to the position of the opening brace for a block. The discussion is 40+ years old and continuing.

Comment: Those are called conventions, and  conventions should be followed, i believe in following conventions,since it gets older with programming language.

Comment: Kindly get it into your head that there is more than one "convention". You may say that you like this style best, but others have the very same right to adhere to another one, or a third one, or yet another one.

Comment: As far as an Individual is concerned ,he might have likes/dislikes. When we are collaborating with others(a Team), these likes and dislikes compromise Readability. That's where convention plays a Role, i think..
And to make points clear "there is Only ONE Convention" and  It is already defined.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode Thanks so much!  Still just learning, so all this is helpful.  Really a shame I need to take this down because I posted it in the wrong forum, but I am copying and pasting EVERYTHING you wrote.  You're awesome !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take  notUniqueNumber and notInRange operations back to the main method, as they just do simple operations, so you would end up with somewhat less code. 
People could argue that by introducing separate methods you can then modify them easily without messing the main method, which is true. This just seems like a small project, so just take into account what is your objective and weight pros and cons.